# How to develop iOS 3.1.3 app in Lion?

Tags: xcode, osx-lion, ios-3.x

I want to develop application for iOS 3.1.3 in Lion OS (10.7.3). Can I develop it? What Xcode I must use to develop iOS 3.1.3 app? Now I use Xcode 4.2.1 and I can create iOS 3.1.3 project cause iOS 5.0 have a different type with 3.1.3.

Thanks before. Regards. :)

Comment: My personal suggestion:Just forget it. Take your time to fix bugs for your App on iOS4 & later.

Comment: Can't we create an iOS 3.1.3 project in Lion?

Comment: I think you can (sorry I don't know how), but needless. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can download additional SDKS from the XCode->Preferences->Downloads. Install older iOS SDK's and simulators, as well as debugging tools from here. After downloading the iOS 3.x and 4.x SDKS, you can build apps that will run on older iOS versions. You then need to set the build versions in the project settings to whatever SDK you want to build. However, you must know that while developing for older versions is a great practice, it may end up being a lot of extra work because different features are not supported (I.e. ARC memory management). Lastly, building for iOS 3.x may be less-useful at this point, because iOS 3 is going to be deprecated in the upcoming months. Just a few things to consider.

Comment: That's for build the app. But how to create the project based on iOS 3.1.3 project, not iOS 5.0 project?

Answer (score 0):

To Change your IOS SDK setting . Simply create your new project and click on your project tab(LEFT PANE).

After that select PROJECT in next LEFT PANE .

After this new tabbar appeared there is 2 tabs INFO/BUILD SETTING .

Select BUILD SETTING . There you find ARCHITECTURE>BASE SDK.

In  Base SDK menu you can select your required SDk to develop your application.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I know to do that. What I want to know is how to create the project based iOS 3.1.3 app. Cause when we create new project we get project with iOS 5.0 app. When I change the project like iOS 3.1.3 project, my app can't show the UI.